# Cannot read property undefined in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have implemented a @input and passing the object details from parent to child. I am getting the following error on initialization of the child component. I am calling a method on the child component on the init method to read the object properties and populate the object. I suspect the @input element is not initialized  when called in that method. I am getting at error on line number 1 of the process method in the NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent.   There is time lag after which it gets initialized. What could be the solution to this problem.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'captiveInsYear' of undefined
```

results.component.ts (parent component)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RunService } from '@wtw/platform/services';
import { Base } from '@wtw/toolkit';
import * as BackendDto from '../../../api/dtos';
import * as BackendProxy from '../../../api/proxies';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-results',
      templateUrl: './results.component.html'
    })
    export class ResultsComponent extends Base.ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
      run: BackendDto.CaptivesRun;
      npvResults: BackendDto.NpvResults;


      sourceResults: BackendDto.NpvResults = {} as BackendDto.NpvResults;

      constructor(
        private _runService: RunService,

      ) {
        super();
      }

      ngOnInit() {

        this._subscriptions  =  [this._runService.activeRun.subscribe((r:  any)  =>  {
          this.run  =  r.data  as  BackendDto.CaptivesRun;

          // Initialising the data

          if  (this.run.strategies) {
            if (!this.run.strategies[0].results) {
              // TODO: push this down to the strategy container and ensure params are set for the strategy id
              this._runService.executeTrigger(r.runId, r.data, { number:  2, param:  ''  }, r.currencyInfo)
              .uiSignal('trigger 2')
              .subscribe(x  =>  {
                this.run  =  x.data;
               // console.log('t2 called');
                this.processResults(x.data.strategies[0].results);
              });
            } else {
               // console.log('t2 not called');
                this.processResults(this.run.strategies[0].results);
            }
          }

        })];

      }

      processResults(results: BackendDto.Results) {
        // TODO: observable results loaded for child components to subscribe to or even better move to a service
        this.npvResults  =  Object.assign({}  as  BackendDto.NpvResults, results.npvResult);

      }

    }
```

**results.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-3 mb-3 test-feasibility--details">

<app-assumptions-summary></app-assumptions-summary>

<app-base-strategy></app-base-strategy>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 test_feasibility--accordion">
        <!-- Accordion -->
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist">

          <app-net-present-value-analysis [NpvResults] = 'npvResults'></app-net-present-value-analysis>

        </div><!-- Accordion End -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**net-present-value-analysis.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NpvResults, ModelingAssumption } from '../../../../api/dtos';
import { BoxPlotChartComponent } from "../../../../shared/HighCharts/box-plot-chart/box-plot-chart.component";
import { AssumptionsService } from '../../../../services/assumptions.service';
import { ReactiveComponent } from '@wtw/toolkit/src/utils/base.component';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-net-present-value-analysis',
  templateUrl: './net-present-value-analysis.component.html',
})
export class NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent extends ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {

  isExpanded = false;
  showTable = true;
  showProjection = true;
  public yearList: number[] = [];
  public sum = (total, currentValue) => { 
    //console.log(currentValue);
    return total + currentValue;
  };


  currentYear = new Date();
  public toYear : number;
  //toYear1 = this.toYear.setFullYear(this.toYear.getFullYear() + 5);
  @Input() NpvResults: NpvResults = {} as NpvResults;



  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.NpvResults);
    // console.log(this.NpvResults[0].captiveDividentDistribution);
    // console.log(this.NpvResults.captiveDividentDistribution);
     this.processYears();

  }

  processYears(){

  let totalYears:any = this.NpvResults.captiveInsYear[this.NpvResults.captiveInsYear.length-1];

   for (var i = 0; i < totalYears; i++) 
    {
      if (i <= 6)
        {
          var val = this.currentYear.getFullYear() + i
          this.yearList.push(val);
        }

    }
       this.toYear = this.yearList[this.yearList.length - 1]

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the NpvResults are loaded in the parent component asynchronously, so when the view renders initially, the NpvResults  is undefined.

You are basically use **`AfterViewChecked`**

```
export class NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent extends ReactiveComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

}
```

Comment: So do i need to remove oninit method

Comment: @Tom Yes, you do not need

Comment: I have added the following export class NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent extends ReactiveComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

Comment: I am getting error  Property 'ngAfterViewChecked' is missing in type 'NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent

Comment: you need to add it to the base component as well, otherwise what you can do is add a ngIf on the parent component to check if NpvResults  exists before passing

Comment: I think the issue is different. This is full error message that i get Class 'NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'AfterViewChecked'.
  Property 'ngAfterViewChecked' is missing in type 'NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent'.

Comment: Do I need to implement the property as well

Comment: Where do i add ngIf on the parent component to check if NpvResults exists before passing

Comment: <app-net-present-value-analysis *ngIf="npvResults" [NpvResults] = 'npvResults'></app-net-present-value-analysis>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164471/discussion-between-tom-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to process data that is sent by an input binding property a good pattern to use is to implement the `OnChanges`. So your child component need to `implement OnChanges`. Then on the actual implementation you can have something like

```
ngOnchanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes.NvpResults && changes.NvpResults.currentValue){
         this.processYears();
    } 
}
```

The `changes` object carries all the changes that happen on all `@Input` bindings. By checking specifically when `NvpResults` binding changes you are ensuring you run the code only when it’s available or when a change actually happened, and also is more efficient in case you have multiple bindings.